# Deploy SSRS 2012 report to a distant Sharepoint 2010 server

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, sharepoint

My installation : 
- SQL server 2008 r2 + Sharepoint server (main farm) = VM1
- SQL server 2012 + SSRS 2012 (not native mode) = VM2

I would like, if possible , make my SSRS configuration manager (VM2) to point to the report server database (VM1).

The problem is that as I installed SSRS in Sharepoint integrated mode (not native), the configuration manager opens and asks for a server and instance. Whatever I try to put in the server case, VM 1 (what I want ) or even VM2 , it can not establish the connection.

Machines ping each others.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Found that : http://it-ebooks.info/book/2961/

But 566 pages, so if anyone can help me to gain time ...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I think it came from the absence of an Active directory to manage users. With it, users are defined precisely and the installation runs perfectly.